# Cancelling out Doppler Effect and Relativistic Time Dilation

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

Let, Alice is moving towards Bob. Relativity will cause Bob's time dilate with respect to Alice, on the other hand Doppler Blues Shift means that signals sent by Bob at 1 second interval will reach at less than 1 second interval to Alice. Does these two effects exactly cancel out so that Alice will see Bob moving at a regular speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that Alice is moving towards Bob with speed $u$.

In Bob's frame of reference, pulses sent by Bob with time interval  $T_B$ between them will be received by Alice with a time interval apart of
$$T_A=T_B-\tfrac 1c uT_A$$
This  is because Alice will have moved a distance $uT_A$ towards Bob between her receiving pulses. Re-arranging
$$T_A=\frac {1}{1+u/c}T_B$$
In Alice's frame (the frame in which she is stationary) the time interval, $T_A'$, between her receiving successive pulses is a proper time whereas $T_A$ is an improper time between the same two events (receiving successive light flashes), so
$$T_A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}T_A'$$
So we have
$$T_A'=\sqrt{\frac{1-u/c}{1+u/c}} T_B$$
So the effects don't cancel!

Comment: Ta' is the proper time where Ta is improper, right? I think you made some typos.

Comment: Thank you. There was indeed a typo. Sorry. $T_A'$ and $T_B$ are both proper times. $T_A$ is improper.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't cancel. The overall effect is to change the perceived clock-rate by a factor which is the apparent change of the clock rate arising from time dilation multiplied by the classic Doppler effect which applies to sound waves, for example.